# ClassCastException- UIMA Ruta

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I get "**java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.Annotation to java.lang.String**" exception  after updating the ruta version from 2.5.0 to 2.6.1 (**Installtion Details attached**). How to resolve this exception ? The exception occurs while executing the below script. Initializing Process taking more time.

**Script:**

```
           FOREACH(hlev) Headinglevel{}
           {
               Document{->tagClass="",onlyClass=true};
               hlev{-> ASSIGN(tagClass,tagName + "." + className), Headinglevel.class = tagClass}
                   <-{TagName{->MATCHEDTEXT(tagName)} # ClassName{->MATCHEDTEXT(className)};};

               CssDefinition{->onlyClass=false, family = CssDefinition.fontfamily, size = CssDefinition.fontsize, color = CssDefinition.fontcolor, bold = CssDefinition.bold, italic = CssDefinition.italic, underline = CssDefinition.underline, case = CssDefinition.case}
                   <-{CssStyles{PARSE(cssStylesStr),IF(contains(cssStylesStr,tagClass))};};                    
           }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Aug 02, 2018 12:07:25 PM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl callAnalysisComponentProcess(434)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed. 
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:563)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:318)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.processFile(RutaLauncher.java:242)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:191)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.Annotation to java.lang.String
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaEnvironment.getVariableValue(RutaEnvironment.java:866)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.expression.string.StringVariableExpression.getStringValue(StringVariableExpression.java:38)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaLiteralMatcher.getMatchingAnnotations(RutaLiteralMatcher.java:51)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaLiteralMatcher.getMatchingAnnotations(RutaLiteralMatcher.java:33)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.getAnchors(RutaRuleElement.java:51)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.startMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:59)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.startMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:76)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:63)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:54)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:36)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.block.ForEachBlock.apply(ForEachBlock.java:92)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.block.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:67)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaModule.apply(RutaModule.java:56)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:561)
```

[image: Installation Details]...

Comment: The exception indicates that you have a feature with range uima.cas.String and you want to assign an annotation. It's hard to identify the source of the problem without known the variable declarations and the type system. (It could of course also be an bug in Ruta,)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using String, I used the annotation name directly.

```
   FOREACH(hlev) Headinglevel{}
           {
               Document{->tagClass="",onlyClass=true};
               Headinglevel{-> ASSIGN(tagClass,tagName + "." + className), Headinglevel.class = tagClass}
                   <-{TagName{->MATCHEDTEXT(tagName)} # ClassName{->MATCHEDTEXT(className)};};

               CssDefinition{->onlyClass=false, family = CssDefinition.fontfamily, size = CssDefinition.fontsize, color = CssDefinition.fontcolor, bold = CssDefinition.bold, italic = CssDefinition.italic, underline = CssDefinition.underline, case = CssDefinition.case}
                   <-{CssStyles{PARSE(cssStylesStr),IF(contains(cssStylesStr,tagClass))};};
           }
```